# Most efficient way to check all words in a json file in python

Tags: python, json, scrabble

I know theres probably a library or something for this but I need it preferably done this way, what I need is to check every word in a json file structured like this:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "aa": 1,
  "aaa": 1,
  "aah": 1,
  "aahed": 1,
  "aahing": 1,
  "aahs": 1,
  "aal": 1,
  "aalii": 1,
  "aaliis": 1,
  "aals": 1,
  "aam": 1,...
```

for a scrabble game where it will find the best word using the letters from variable 'word' and find the most point worthy word in that json file by calculating each of its points from a dictionary like this:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 2,
  "d": 3,
  "e": 1,...
```

^ the letters and their scrabble "points"

I wouldve done something like threading and for looping but for 370,000 words its not that efficient

I can also change seperately change the values of the words to be the points instead of 1's if that would speed up the check process

Doing it using the normal for loop just crashed the program since its 370k words

Comment: How can you precompute the value of a word when it depends on where the word is placed? Also, 370k words should not "crash" the problems. It is just taking long? If it's crashing, there is another problem.

Comment: I wrote a scrabble scorer some time back, there's probably a better way: create a prefix-tree from the list of possible words, 1) find positions where the word can start, 2) add letters to the word as long as the prefix (incl. existing letters on the board) is in the prefix-tree (i.e. not all combinations); 3) if the prefix is an actual word, calculate the score (incl. bonuses); 4) pick the word with best score.